# Customize OAuth2 error response on client authentication with Spring Security

Tags: java, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

While this seems to be an easy task, it turns out the opposite. I'm trying to customize the error handling for OAuth2 client authentication requests. The purpose of this is to remove the exception stacktrace/message from the response message.

#### Context

- vanilla Oauth2 Spring Security implementation
- Java Spring configuration

#### Steps taken to accomplish the task

1. Create a custom implementation of `OAuth2ExceptionRenderer`
2. Create a `@Bean` instance of `OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint`

   ```
   @Bean
   public OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint clientAuthEntryPoint()
   {
       OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint clientEntryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
       clientEntryPoint.setTypeName("Basic");
       clientEntryPoint.setRealmName("my-realm/client");
       clientEntryPoint.setExceptionRenderer(new CustomOAuth2ExceptionRenderer());
       return clientEntryPoint;
   }
   ```
3. Create an access denied handler

   ```
   @Bean
   public OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler()
   {
       OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler adh = new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
       adh.setExceptionRenderer(new CustomOAuth2ExceptionRenderer());
       return adh;
   }
   ```
4. Augment the `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer`, among others, with these specialized implementations in `AuthorizationServerConfiguration`

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableAuthorizationServer
   protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
   {
       @Override
       public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception
       {
           oauthServer.authenticationEntryPoint(clientAuthEntryPoint());
           oauthServer.accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
           oauthServer.realm("my-realm");
       }
   }
   ```

#### OAuth2 request

We use curl to initiate OAuth2 reuqests. Here is the command we use to test the client authenticaiton:

```
curl --insecure -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -iu adfadsf:asdvadfgadf "https://localhost:8430/oauth/token?grant_type=password$username=john&pasword=johny"
```

#### Observed behavior

Since the client authentication is a Basic authentication, Spring Security will assign a `BasicAuthenticationFilter` to that step. If it happens to have an error in the backend related to this step (e.g. SQL exception), Spring Security will not pick up the `OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint` and will fall-back to a default entry point `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

#### Logs

````
o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: show me the money
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@649f92da
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed```
````

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: The solution we had is to make sure no Exception leaks from that method (`loadClientByClientId` in our case). This is elegant not, but it works. I've also put a question on their issue tracker and it's still open. Feel free to make your point there too. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/483

Answer (score 0):

You could try the solution posted by Roman Wozniak on your ticket [#483](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/483#issuecomment-222499830). It worked pretty well for me :)

- Code by Roman Wozniak:

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableAuthorizationServer
  protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    //...

      @Override
      public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
          oauthServer
                      .realm(RESOURCE_ID + "/client")
                      .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                      .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);

          // This allows you to replace default filter for Basic authentication and customize error responses
          oauthServer.addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(
                  new BasicAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, entryPoint));
          }
  }
  ```