# Custom render of Spring Oauth2 errors

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

How can I change the render of Spring Oauth2 errors? For example when you try to access rest resource which is protected without providing `Bearer` header, this error is rendered by Spring Framework :

```
<oauth>
<error_description>Full authentication is required to access this resource</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

I want it to render like my other API responses and error messages which I am handling with @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler annotations.

I have tried to provide WebResponseExceptionTranslator but it only triggers when I provide bad credentials.

I see that the `DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer` is responsible for rendering this errors, but could not manage to change it.

Comment: does this helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262600/customize-oauth2-error-response-on-client-authentication-with-spring-security   (`...accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler`)

Comment: and this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/691